# run script in cron job that contains sudo

Tags: scripts, sudo, cron

I need to write a script that will restart the DB server and run the application

I know how to write the script and how to make it in crontab to run after a reboot

my problem that I need to do some commands that need to use `sudo` how to include password in sudo command in the script

Comment: did you try using root's crontab by `sudo crontab -e`?

Comment: You don't include sudo inside the script. You run the script as root. Or you use two scripts that communicate: One root, the other user. Or you use systemd instead of crontab, which is designed for *exactly* this use case.